# Can a solidity function take bytecode as a parameter and deploy it?

Tags: solidity

I know a smart contract can deploy another contract if both contracts are in scope of the same file. I'm wondering if I can write a contract that has its own `deployBytecode()` function. You would call the deployBytecode() function and pass in the bytecode, and the existing smart contract would create that contract.

Is this possible yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for `create`. Something like this:

```
function deploy(bytes _bytecode) external returns (address) {
    address addr;
    bytes memory bytecode = _bytecode;

    assembly {
        addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
    }

    return addr;
}
```